# Distribution of a random variable to the nth power

Tags: probability, distributions

If we know the distribution of $X$ is symmetric, do we know anything about the shape of the distribution of $X^n$, where $n\geq 0$ but is not necessarily an integer?

I'm not referring to the moments of $X$, but rather the distribution of its products (but more generally, raised to the $n$th power).

Edit: as many have pointed out, I should clarify further that $x$ is assumed to have the domain $[a,b]$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers.  Symmetric refers to symmetric around the mean, a positive number

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of "symmetric".  If you mean symmetric *about zero*, then you will need to restrict the possible values of $n$, because the $n$th power of negative values may be undefined.  It would help to focus your question further, because about the most specific answer that can be made in general is that the distribution of $X^n$ can literally be anything--and very few statements (that aren't completely obvious) can be made about the relationship between the two distributions.

Comment: For example, $(-3)^{1/2}$ is undefined (in ℝ). Even if the symmetry is around a positive number instead of $0$, this is still an issue if $X$ can be negative.